# Search oracle database php

Tags: php, oracle

I try this sql query for searching oracle database using php but I have getting error

Notice: Undefined index: BUILDING

Notice: Undefined index: COUNTRY

Notice: Undefined index: STATE

```
$query ="SELECT  * FROM LOCATION WHERE(LOCATION LIKE '%".$_GET["LOCATION"]."%' 
                          or BUILDING LIKE '%".$_GET["BUILDING"]."%' or COUNTRY LIKE '%".$_GET["COUNTRY"]."%'
            or STATE LIKE '%".$_GET["STATE"]."%') ";
```

Comment: Are you submitting your info via web forms...are you sure the input fields in your form matches those names...and, are you sure the form method is set to get??

Answer (score 0):

First off that may be a seriously dangerous script in means of injection risks. (clean your inputs if you have not already done so!)

The undefined Index suggests that the array $_GET does not contain the indexes you are asking for I.e. Does not exist.

Make sure that you have ? or & BUILDING=something in your URL.
(for example http://example.com/?BUILDING=mybuilding&COUNTRY=Sweden)

If you have posted the data with a form make sure you have get as the method of the form.
The indexes are case-sensitive so building does not equal BUILDING

Answer (score 0):

You must to fetch in your php code there are some index called BUILDING,COUNTRY,STATE is empty from the database and the php index cannot contain any empty value.